# I don't see affect if I write assert true or assert false. why?

Tags: java, assertion

I faced with assertion in java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert true;
        assert false;
    }
```

I don't understand why I don;t see assertion error at this case?

What do this code snippet do?

Comment: Enable assertions with `java -ea`.

Comment: How can I make it in IDEA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assertions need to be enabled when you launch the JVM e.g.

```
$ java -ea ...
```

See [the doc for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable).

> By default, assertions are disabled at runtime. Two command-line
>   switches allow you to selectively enable or disable assertions.
>
> To enable assertions at various granularities, use the
>   -enableassertions, or -ea, switch

Note that you can enable/disable *per class/package* if you require.

As to how you perform this with IDEA, you need to [modify the VM options](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) for your particular run/debug configuration.

Comment: if I write * assert true; * - it is full analog of empty string?